# DOM element is clicking in debuggin mode, but not in executing in Selenium WebDrvier

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have code to click on Radio button like this,

```
clickElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("radio.security.team.exists.outside.yes")), "RadioExistOutside");
```

clickElement is the generic method to click on element by xpath

I have taken this xpath and put it in FirePath, it found that element, inspected that element in command line and `$p.click();` did this.. it is able to click on it... I think there is no problem with xpath...

I went to debugging mode and put debugging points over these lines, when I step over it, it is click on the element, but when I run the script, it is not able to click.

I thought that thread acceleration might be causing this and put a wait before it, but it didn't worked? please help me in this...

Comment: which language you are using to click radio button? clickElement is a method? pls post full code.

Comment: can you try with some wait. If possible can you please post the error message that you are getting.

Comment: Hi, what is the exception you are facing? or that click command executing without exception but not correctly simulated on execution? if click is done but not simulated you can try click again and see.. if not you can use javascriptExecutor as specified in below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For xpath you need to share your HTML code so we can verify the xpath

While you can try with JavascriptExecutor to click your radio button

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR Locator"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Note:- feel free to change the locator in above code according to your convenience.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I am not authorized to share that, I have checked in firepath panel,it is uniquely finding the element, even in debugging mode it is clicking on that, but in execution, it is failed to click. I also tried to get that element in firepath command line and used $p.click(); it is clicking... My doubt is if it is clicking on debugging mode, it should also click on execution. Why it is not clicking?

Comment: try to pass some wait before it ... in real execution it far fast then debugging mode and did you try my provided code?

Comment: Your code worked, but what's the difference between driver.findelement(xpath).click(); and your code?

Comment: Thanks @Lokesh S for accepting the answer. The difference is javascriptEcecutor directly work on HTML DOM as name suggest it's a java script. This interface is also provided by selenium. For more details please refer :- https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: is radio button will not come under category of being clickable by selenium webdriver?

Comment: It is comes under same. But I can't tell anything without seem your HTML code. Many times I found this issue occurring in chrome while in firefox everything is working fine.

Comment: You want whole DOM structure or this is enough  div class="radio radio-success radio-inline">
<input id="27yes" type="radio" checked="" value="yes" name="27">
<label for="27yes"> Yes </label>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571048/selenium-webelement-click-vs-javascript-click-event

Comment: I have used .//input[@id='27yes'] as xpath