# I have to click on login button in a website.It is a ajax call.Which is the best method to click the element?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium

I have to click on login button in a website.It is a ajax call.Which is the best method to click the element?

Webelement.click() or Javascriptexecutor??

Comment: What do you mean by "Best method"? Portability? Performance?

Comment: I assume the best method would be to do it with pure javascript. Because it's faster than JQuery. But for one single action JQuery is also fine if I had to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**You are talking about two different things.**

To test Ajax application, different wait methods should be applied as AJAX allows the Web page to retrieve small amounts of data from the server without reloading the entire page.

**Wait methods to be applied:**

ThreadSleep

Implicit Wait

Explicit Wait

WebdriverWait

Fluent Wait

**After the element is visible on the page you can click on the element by using JavascriptExecutor or WebElement.click.**

**Please refer the stackoverflow link:**

[Selenium WebElement.click() vs. Javascript click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571048/selenium-webelement-click-vs-javascript-click-event) for understanding the difference between Javascript executor and Webdriver click,

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit wait for element to be clickable and then use click provided by webdriver. 
JavaScript click calls the function onClick(), which will not trigger other mouse events which might have been registered to that button.
Where as the webdriver click simulates the user click on browser, this has most close resemblance to how user interacts with the application.

Answer (score 0):

As the Question have `Java` tag here are my 2 cents:

Considering we are working with Selenium through `Java` bindings the solution will depend from Application to Application. We have to come to a conclusion which method works best as per the **`AUT (Application Under Test)`** and the available **`Test Environment`**. The following may be a good sequence to follow:

1. **`WebElement.click()`**
2. **`Actions Class`**
3. **`JavaScriptExecutor`**

> Considering it to be a AJAX call, when we try with **`WebElement.click()`**, it is worth to be mentioned that, `ExplicitWait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` may come into play, either for `visibility` or `invisibility` of elements (other elements).

Let me know if this Answers your Question.